# collapsible panels with overlay in border layout extjs

Tags: extjs, overlay, panel, border-layout, collapsable

I am using border layout with two panels in east and center as its items and by default if i make the east panel collapsible then it will resize the center panel when expanded or collapsed. I want to know if this nature can be changed in such a way that when the east panel is expanded , it overlays on the center panel rather than sharing the total width it.
Below image might give some idea what i want to achieve.
[image]

thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the panel is [floatable](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-floatable), so just need to hide the collapse tool to achieve it

Sample fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1gs

Comment: thanks @newmount that code works...i would still like to know if there is any possible way of doing this same thing with the collapsible button config set to true ?

Comment: also if configured this way will the expand and collapse events of east panel fire because i am not able to capture them right now..!

Comment: use 'float' and 'unfloat' events.. updated the fiddle

Comment: I got the same problem anyone can provide idea? i have spent two days searching no luck